# Calling a method from another class and modifying its variables

Tags: java, methods, instance

Still learning the proper way to use instances with java and i am having a difficult time calling a method from one class to another:

/***/

```
public class MainView extends CustomComponent{

  private Panel viewPanel;

  /*Method i am trying to call*/
  public Panel getPanel{
    return this.viewPanel;
   }
 }


Public class FormView extends CustomComponent{

   private MainView mview;    
   private Panel tempPanel;

    public FormView(){

     buildLayout(); 
     mView = new MainView();  /// Stackoverflow Error
     tempPanel = mView.getPanel(); // Stackoverflow Error
    } 
}
```

I am running into an infinite loop when i try to access the MainView 'Panel' variable?

Stack Trace:

```
org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerApplication.createLoginWindow(DugsiManagerApplication.java:49)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerApplication.init(DugsiManagerApplication.java:28)
        at com.vaadin.Application.start(Application.java:554)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.startApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1213)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:484)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:344)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:288)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.AdministrationView.<init>(AdministrationView.java:290)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:417)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.ui.LoginForm.<init>(LoginForm.java:448)
        at org.bixin.dugsi.web.LoginWindow.<init>(LoginWindow.java:14)
        at
```

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem you are having. There is no way to tell from the snippits you post above as to what is going on. The stack trace would also be helpful. I suspect the problem is going to be in your `CustomComponent` ... if my ESP is working, you're recursively instantiating something either as a field or in the constructor.

Comment: I can't see the problem there, can you get a stack trace of the top few lines to see where it's happening?

Comment: added the stack trace, sorry for not posting an SSCCE, there is alot of boiler plate code and i am using a framework that does generates a large amount of hidden code.

Comment: You obviously have a recursive initialization problem as I suspected. `MainView` creates whatever `AdministrationView` is which creates a `MainView` which creates an `AdministrationView` and so on. Since you don't show a constructor for `MainView` it's in the super class' constructor (`CustomComponent`) or a field in that class or in code you're not showing us (The constructor for `MainView`.)

Comment: @BrianRoach Thanks for this catch, i haven't fixed the problem yet but this helps me understand the infinite Runtime exception i was getting. The constructor for {MainView} is exactly the same as the constructor for {AdministrationView}, if i create a new constructor inside my 'AdministrationView' that takes as a parameter an instance of MainView like so: Public AdministrationView(MainView mView){this.mainView = mView } and then call AdministrationView with this new constructor in my MainView class, will i still have this problem?

Comment: @BrianRoach Thanks to your help i figured out what my problem was. i created a new constructor to reference my mainView class. How can i vote your answer

Comment: I'll post it as an answer to your question, one sec. And thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have a recursive initialization problem.

`MainView` creates whatever `AdministrationView` is which creates a `MainView` which creates an `AdministrationView` and so on.

Since you don't show a constructor for `MainView` it's in the super class' constructor (`CustomComponent`) or a field in that class or in code you're not showing us (The constructor for `MainView`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Panel getPanel() { //<----add parenthesis to make this a method!
  return this.viewPanel;
 }
```

You need to add parenthesis in order for you to be able to call the method `getPanel()`.

```
public class FormView extends CustomComponent{ //changed Public to public (no capital P)
```

You probably meant public instead of Public. The compiler is going to try to interpret Public as a variable or function name instead of a keyword when it has a capital P.

```
 mView = new MainView();  /// Stackoverflow Error
 tempPanel = mView.getPanel(); // Stackoverflow Error
```

It appears to me that the first line is fine as it will just invoke the default constructor and initialize all of the variables in the class to null, and the second one will merely return null since that's how `viewPanel` was initialized.

The problem probably lies somewhere in your `CustomComponent` class that you haven't posted yet. As others before me have already said, posting it and a stack-trace would help us help you. :D

Comment: I wrote sample code just to get an explanation of instance creation. I posted the stack trace

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that the main reason for your stackoverflow error is both the MainView and FormView are inherited the CustomComponent so when the constructor method is invoked,it will also execute the CustomComponent's constructor method twice!!,but I can't give more details because I am ignorant with the CustomComponent